# CSS Positioning/Floating

Tags: html, css

I have a working snake game but I can't seem to get the CSS to display properly. The style I am going for is to have a sidebar that is directly adjacent to my game on the right side (kind of like float left?) but I've exhausted my reportoire. I have tried using inline blocks and multiple floats with no success. The images I have are basically absolutely positioned (using transform translate: xx) because when I put the image tags within my details div, it seems to only render one of the images. I ended up adding a bunch of line breaks and then moving the images directly in between the empty spots. You can see what I want below on my github page (except I'd rather it be responsive to screen size rather than break when the screen gets smaller).

http://jeffreycheng92.github.io/SnakeGame/html/

```
// these are both images and my current (unwanted) css

.arrows {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  transform: translate(-93%, -150%);
}

.p { 
  display: inline-block;
  left: 25px;
  float: left;
  transform: translate(75%);
}
```

You can see my code below although my html positioning seems to be completely broken on jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/g9c6wfs7/

Comment: so all you need is to place .details to be on left side of game right?

Comment: @NeelShah I actually need them on the right side of the game as shown on the github page except not absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about your html structure, but what you need; some how i managed to get that. Check [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g9c6wfs7/26/).

I hope this may give you some idea.

Also would like to give some suggestion;

- Use `<span>` for small text content so that you can easily manipulate              structure.
- Instead of using `<br />` for making space, use **margin**

Answer (score 1):

You just need the arrows on the right side of the square, correct? If some elements are in the flow (`position: static`) and some are out of the flow (`position: relative, absolute, or fixed`), it'd be nigh impossible to do a cohesive layout.

> ... absolutely positioned (using transform translate: xx) because when I put the image tags within my details div, it seems to only render one of the images.

Have you tried background images on a div? That'll make your images not only blocks but positioned with other positioned elements so no cutoffs. `background-size: cover`?

**Update:** Here's something that you should look into: [Multiple Backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds)

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/p328nh3d/)**

**CSS**

```
.container { position: relative; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }
.arrows {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 5%;
  display: inline-block;

  /*transform: translate(-93%, -150%);*/
}
```